# How do use a custom data type with ngModel in Angular Dart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-ngmodel, angular-dart

I'm building an app in AngularDart, and so far it's going well. I particularly love how easy it makes forms. However, I'm running into a little snag in that regard.

Basically what I want to do is have the ngModel of a given form element work with a different data type, converting back and forth between the two as needed. For example, I am using an `<input type='number'/>` element in my HTML, but on the dart business logic side of things I'd like to deal with that value as a Dart `Decimal` class (from here: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal) because I need to avoid floating point issues.

I make pretty extensive use of 2-way data binding and ngModel in my app because it's awesome and works well for this application. However, ngModel doesn't work in this particular case. Obviously I can work around it, but I'm hoping for a little more elegance. I'd like to be able to specify some class or function that would allow me to do type conversion with ngModel.

I've looked around on Google and in the documentation and suspect my solution has something to do with using a Form Control, although I'm a little confused on how exactly this would work. I'm having a hard time finding much relevant example code or documentation to what I'm trying to do. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree there.

Here's a super simplified example of what I'd like to be able to accomplish if I can figure out what I need to do:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '...<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="thing.attr"/>...'
)
class MyComponent{

  DataObject thing = new DataObject();
}

class DataObject{
  Decimal attr;
}
```

I imagine this is something that I'm likely to run into a lot is the need to do type conversion, not just specifically in this case with the `Decimal` class, so any help or advice anyone has would be much appreciated.

---

### Update

I was able to make some good progress based on Ted Sander's answer below, but it's still not quite working for me and I'm not sure why.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

@Directive(
  selector: 'input[type=decimal][ngControl],'
      'input[type=decimal][ngFormControl],'
      'input[type=decimal][ngModel]',
)
class DecimalValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  final InputElement _element;

  DecimalValueAccessor(HtmlElement element) : _element = element as InputElement;

  @HostListener('change', ['\$event.target.value'])
  @HostListener('input', ['\$event.target.value'])
  void handleChange(String value) {
    print('About to parse decimal');
    Decimal dec;
    try{
      dec = new Decimal.parse(value);
    }
    catch (e){
      //TODO: mark feild as invalid
      return;
    }
    print('Got $dec with type ${dec.runtimeType}');
    onChange((value == '' ? null : dec), rawValue: value);
  }

  void writeValue(value) {
    _element.value = '$value';
  }

  void onDisabledChanged(bool isDisabled) {
    _element.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  TouchFunction onTouched = () {};

  @HostListener('blur')
  void touchHandler() {
    onTouched();
  }

  /// Set the function to be called when the control receives a touch event.
  void registerOnTouched(TouchFunction fn) {
    onTouched = fn;
  }

  ChangeFunction<Decimal> onChange = (Decimal _, {String rawValue}) {};

  /// Set the function to be called when the control receives a change event.
  void registerOnChange(ChangeFunction<Decimal> fn) {
     onChange = fn;
  }
}
```

It seems to work okay going one way: if I change the value programatically it seems to pick it up and work fine. However, if I change it via the input, it throws an exception `Type 'String' is not a subtype of expected type 'Decimal'.`

I added some print statement as you can see, just to make sure the type conversion code is actually running. It prints out "About to parse decimal" and "Got 1.55 with type Decimal" as I would expect. However, I notice this shows up not before but *after* the exception is thrown in the console, which is really confusing me. Does anyone have any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: I don't see the provider to tell the forms system that it is a ControlValueAccessor: providers: [ExistingProvider.forToken(ngValueAccessor,DecimalValueAccessor)],

Comment: Perfect, adding that line made everything work! Seem like a weird way to tell Angular that it's a ControlValueAccessor, but hey, it works so I'm happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excellent question. The thing that you are looking for is the ControlValueAccessor. It is responsible for reading/writing/converting values from a DOM Element, or Component.

You can see the angular_forms number version [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/number_value_accessor.dart).

A more complicated angular_component version is [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/angular_components/lib/material_input/material_number_accessor.dart).

You'll want to create one of these that basically does what the angular_forms version does, but doesn't use `double.parse`. The directive that you create I would suggest giving it a selector of `input[type=decimal]` so that it doesn't conflict with the one provided by forms, and add that directive to your directives list in the components where you want to use it.

Glad you are liking AngularDart so far!

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me get on the right track. I think I'm still missing something though. I've added an update with my current code. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: second link is dead